How to set PTS connection parameters request procedure feature bit?
I'm doing a PTS test. The test case is GAP/CONN/CPUP/BV-04-C. In the initial condition, it says "On the lower tester, set the Connection Parameters Request Procedure LL feature bit to 0". I want to know how can i set PTS's feature bit.
I have set my device feature bit to 0. But I don't know how to set the PTS feature bit.
